# Animations Array Loads Slowly. How can I speed the process up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation

we're loading about 30 full 320 x 480 images into an animations array. These images are very small in size at about 5 - 7Kb per images. The problem is when we run the loop to populate an array for the images, it seems to pause the entire app while this array get's populated. Is there perhaps a way to load this mutable array with the images in a separate thread or something to allow the array to populate without hurting performance? Thanks

```
    NSMutableArray *totalAnimationImages  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numOfImages];

for(int i = 1; i < numOfImages; i++) {
    [totalAnimationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", image, i]]];
}

annImage.animationImages = totalAnimationImages;
annImage.animationDuration = speed; //.4 second
annImage.animationRepeatCount = 1; //infinite loop

[annImage startAnimating]; //start the animation

[totalAnimationImages release];
```

In working with this issue, and using the threading suggestion provided by shabzco, I've come up with the below code to process a loop, changing the image in an image view, with what seem to be absolutely no performance hit. This only holds one image at a time instead of 30 in an NSMutableArray. Just as  Richard J. Ross III said, as soon as the animation would start it would be processing all of the images "into a in-memory bitmap format". This is where the long wait / lag came from. In the below code this is only happening once per image update instead of 30 just to start the animation. I use the while loop with timer in the suggested dispatch thread to keep this timer from effecting the main thread thus potentially creating jerky performance during animations. Please provide feedback on this solution! Thanks

UPDATE: Shabzco suggested that I replace the "ImageNamed" with "imageWithContentsOfFile" to avoid strange memory leaks due to ImageNamed potentially caching images in memory. This was discovered after running xcode profiler and watching the "Real Memory" counter. It became evident that every time an animation ran, the real memory would increase more and more until ultimately the app would crash. After replacing "ImageNamed" with "imageWithContentsOfFile" the issue went away. I've updated the below code.

```
annImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
[annImage setAlpha:1.0];
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{ 
    NSTimeInterval timeout = 1.00 / speed;   // Number of seconds before giving up
    NSTimeInterval idle = 1.00 / 8;     // Number of seconds to pause within loop
    BOOL timedOut = NO;
    NSDate *timeoutDate;
    for(int i = 1; i < numOfImages; i++) {
        timeoutDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeout];
        timedOut = NO;
        while (!timedOut)
        {
            NSDate *tick = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:idle];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:tick];
            timedOut = ([tick compare:timeoutDate] == NSOrderedDescending);
            [tick release];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //annImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
            //                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", image, i]];
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", image, i] ofType:@"png"];
            annImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        });   
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.3];
        [annImage setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that it has to convert the png data into a in-memory bitmap format... I'm not entirely sure if the UIImage class is thread-safe, so you are best off just trying yourself with a simple GCD queue.

Comment: Consider making an atlas of your images, and animating them using a simple trick described in [this article](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/).

Comment: Do you load the array many times per running of your application, or only once? i.e.: If you put a breakpoint on the code, do you hit it more than once in one run? If so it may be that you just need to make that mutable array hang around for the life of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your for loop happen in a different thread and will start animating once everything has been loaded.

```
@autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *totalAnimationImages  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numOfImages];
        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{   
            for(int i = 1; i < numOfImages; i++) {
                [totalAnimationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:
                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", image, i]]];
            }
            annImage.animationImages = totalAnimationImages;
            annImage.animationDuration = speed; //.4 second
            annImage.animationRepeatCount = 1; //infinite loop
            [annImage startAnimating]; //start the animation
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [totalAnimationImages release];

            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've added this code and tried it out. The populating of the array seems to be fast and does not effect the performance of the app. However, as soon as "startAnimating" gets called there is a pause of a few seconds. Is there some way to resolve this pause? I fear that this is simply due to the fact the the start animating is calling up 30 images. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I just gave that a shot but the animation did not start. I don't think it started because I was trying from within the dispatch thread.

Comment: I've just updated my original question. Does this look like a good solution to you? Thanks!

Comment: I have the above working fairly well, but, I'm having an issue now when I send the app to analyze in the profiler. As soon as the 30 image run takes place the app increases in mem very quickly and suddenly the app crashes. This never happens in normal running mode but if there is a men problem with the above implementation I would rather not take chances. Is it possible that each image loaded is then converted then stored in memory and not released? I'm only displaying one image at a time in the UIImageView but it seems like each previous image sticks around in memory.

Comment: Ok, I've added the @autoreleasepool to the code. Now the animation will run properly in the profiler without crashing. However, the "Real Memory" continues to increase and does not release. Every time the animation runs, it seems that each image is being stored in memory causing the "Real Memory" to increase until the OS has had enough and crashes the app. This may take a long time to happen but I've seen this a few times. We've since reduced the size of the images even further but there's not much else we can do. Any suggestions? Thanks for your fast replies!

Comment: instead of using -imageNamed use -imageWithContentsOfFile. -imageNamed caches images, and sometimes the system has a problem knowing when to release them. -imageWithContentsOfFile will not cache your images at all

Comment: YES! This was exactly right! Thank you so much I'm going to update my code earlier in this post and credit your work. I'm also going to make some other changed in my apps using this instead. Thank you immensely shabzco!